# Best Way To Store Roster In SQL Database

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design

I'm working on a roster system for my workplace and was wondering what the best way of storing roster information in the database would be i.e there are staff members already in the database, and every staff member would have roster information for each day that there is a shift rostered to them - similar to findmyshift.com.

Comment: This seems more like an open-ended design discussion than a coding question.

Answer (score 4):

You haven't really given us enough information to go on.  However. Barry Williams's library of free data models has a simple model for a Nurses' Roster, which you could adapt for your needs.  [Find it her](http://www.databaseanswers.org/data_models/nurses_roster/index.htm)e.